# Ionic nav pop in 3rd level view does not update 2nd level page (stroage data change)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I got 3 level deep nav with views in Ionic 3.

In the first view I get data from local storage and output a list

**page 1**

> ```
> getPrograms() {
>    this.storage.get("fetchedData").then(val => {
>    if (val.hasOwnProperty("programs")) {
>      this.programs = val.programs;
>
>      for (var i = 0; i < this.programs.length; i++) {
>       if (this.programs[i].exercises.length) {
>         this.exercises.push(this.programs[i].exercises);
>       }
>     }
>    }
>   });   
>  }
>
> itemTapped(event, program) {
>   this.navCtrl.push(Exercises, {
>   programs: program
> });   }
> ```

and then in the second view I get data with params from the first view and generate another list (from params data)

**page 2**

> ```
>  this.currentProgram = this.navParams.get("programs"); 
>
>  getExercises() {
>   if (this.currentProgram.hasOwnProperty("exercises")) {
>   this.exercises = this.currentProgram.exercises;    
> }
>
> seeDetails(event, exercise) {
>   this.navCtrl.push(ExerciseDetails, {
>     exercises: exercise
>    });  
> }
> ```

In the third view I get data from the second view with params

**page 3**

> ```
> this.item = navParams.get("exercises");
> ```
>
> and then when user submit some
>    changes and they are posted to external API I do the change to the
>    storage value
>
> ```
>    getUpdatedData() {
>    this.storage.remove("fetchedData").then(() => { 
>      //make request to API for refreshed data from endpoint
>      this.programsService.getPrograms(userhash).subscribe(res => {
>        if (res != null && res != undefined) {
>              this.storage.set("fetchedData", res).then(() => {
>                  this.loader.dismiss();
>                  this.navCtrl.pop();
>              });
>        }
>      });
>    });   
>   }
> ```

So when I pop from the 3 level view with getUpdatedData() there’s no update in the 2nd level data (storage is changed so this should be somehow reflected in the first view and then passed to second view)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code is working as it should.
Problem is that: you add data to storage(probably sqllite) but in the second page you dont check that data. My suggestion is using Events.

on your page3 componnent you should do right after your pop on nav controller

```
this.events.publish('data:updated');
```

then in your page2's constructor you subscribe for that event by using

```
this.events.subscribe('data:updated', () => {
  this.updateData();
})

updateData(){
  //now get your saved data here and use it to update your fields
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. The problem is I am getting data in the first view pass them to second view and then to third. So When I click button in the 3rd view and it triggers storage value change - the changed value should appear in the second view. 
Events works fine (thanks for the info about it) - click triggers change in the storage in the first view runs the function but the second view is not updated (params probably not updated)

Comment: if (val.hasOwnProperty("programs")) does this if runs on second time. In other words does your data returns with programs when you update it?

Comment: yes - getPrograms  returns new updated data when  event is triggered in the third view. But value is not updated the value in the 2nd view that is being displayed after nav.pop()

Comment: As I understand you only push second view once. If thats the case you still need to look out for that data in your second view as i proposed in the answer. Because when you push your page data only sent there once from first page until you pop it and push it back with parameters from first page it will stay the same. A using events might be a workaround for that since you cant pop with parameters. There are some examples using callback tho. you might want to look at them

Comment: Thanks! I was having trouble because ionViewWillEnter wasn't triggering when using nav pop, with events it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try with async which expects an observable and it takes the gives latest updated value.

https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

This worked for me.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)